# how to create a resposnsive diamond shaped div with icons and border?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-shapes

I am trying to create a diamond shaped div with a border around it. but the problem i am facing is that it needs to be responsive and the shape is also unusual. attaching a image for reference.

[image: Imgur]

I have created a custom icon font using icomoon app. The text next to the icon links also need to be responsive

My attempt so far:

```css
.diamond {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #626262;
  margin-top: 20px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.diamond i {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.diamond .top {
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.diamond .bottom {
  margin-top: 10px
}
.diamond .top.left,
.diamond .bottom.left {
  margin-left: -10px;
}
.diamond .top.right,
.diamond .bottom.right {
  margin-right: -10px;
}
i.socialicn {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 6px;
  background-color: #8a4d8e;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 17px;
}
i.socialfb {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background-color: #8a4d8e;
  border-radius: 50%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="diamond center-block">
          <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="pull-left"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook top left socialfb"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter top right socialicn"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="pull-left"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope bottom left socialicn"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin bottom right socialicn"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At least give it a try before you ask for code...

Comment: Not able to see the image you attached, may be u forgot to attach.
Post some code and the result you want as well.

Comment: You'll need to either create an SVG image and use it inline (not supported in IE8) or do it in CSS (which will require 2D transforms, also not supported in IE8).  SVG will allow for smooth scaling of text, but if any of those are intended to be links, that will make it more complicated than CSS.

Comment: Heres a fiddle @Chrillewoodz 
http://jsfiddle.net/ok14x98b/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like:

```css
.wrap {
  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 5px solid black;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
transform-origin:top left;
  min-width:60px;min-height:60px;
}
.wrap a {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.wrap a:first-child {
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
}
.wrap a:not(:nth-child(3)) b{position:absolute; left:150%; width:auto;}
.wrap a:nth-child(2) {
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
}
.wrap a:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: -15px;
  left: -15px;
}
.wrap a:nth-child(4) {
  bottom: -15px;
  right: -15px;
}
.wrap a:nth-child(3) b{position:absolute; right:150%; width:auto;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#">1 <b>Text</b></a>
  <a href="#">2 <b>Text</b></a>
  <a href="#">3 <b>Text</b></a>
  <a href="#">4 <b>Text</b></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Heres a fiddle of what i have done

http://jsfiddle.net/ok14x98b/

Comment: I want to add text next to the icons like its shown in the image

Comment: @prawwe316: added some text for you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.diamond {
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: relative;
    margin: 25%;
}
.cell {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: tomato;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;    
}
.t-l {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
.t-r {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
.b-l {
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
.b-r {
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    transform: translate(50%, 50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/hx74xqgv/4/)**